# Adding the app made by pyinstaller to the windows app list

Tags: python

I have a question...

If I create an app using pyinstaller and turn it into an exe, I want the app added to the windows app list in the start menu...Here:

[App list in start menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJSsi.jpg)

How do I do this...It's fine even if I need to add something to my code. I can compile it again. Please help thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the .ink shortcut of the .exe to *%APPDATA%/Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs*